# Maven manage dependencies via another pom

Tags: java, maven, war

I have two maven projects.

```
-- my-common-lib
-- my-web-application
```

my-common-lib - contains just a pom which all dependencies.
my-web-application - is a web application.

Is there a maven plugin which I can define in "my-application" pom that makes that all dependencies defined in "my-common-lib" should not be added to "WEB-INF/lib" when building my-web-application project .

Thanks 
Sundar

Comment: Please clarify some of your expressions (just to be sure to understand you correctly): What do you mean by "I have a war that exposes all these dependencies"? What exactly do you want to do? You want the dependencies from your other pom NOT to appear in your war?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to import dependencies from the other artifact.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sample<groupId>
            <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type> 
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: This will only influence the information in the dependencyManagement but not the dependencies itself.